# Android Animation fill color left to right

Tags: android, animation

I have a menu with multiple menuitems in a list, each item is a relativelayout. 
How can i fill the background of these relativelayouts with a different
color for each menu item, from left to right?

Comment: feed your `Menuadatper` with a list of colors (coming from XML colors.xml file, for example) and in your `getView()` method apply the corresponding background